# Having Problem Trying To Use and Update Variables Inside Plain Dart Text - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I am quite new to Flutter & Dart. I have a plain dart class called "Faith" and this class is not wrapped in any widget. Been trying to use variables/states inside choices and event title. How should I be creating, using and updating variables/states inside plain Dart class? Thanks in advance.

```
class Faith{
  String? childsName = "Joe";

  List<Events> _simulation= [
    Events(
      eventCode: 0,
      eventTitle:
          "Welcome ${childsName}, to the world of darkness.",
      eventImage: "assets/images/welcoming.jpg",
      choices: [
        Choice(choiceText: "Continue"),
        Choice(choiceText: "Go Back"),
      ],
    ),
  ];
```

I have looked for state management tools such as Riverpod and native flutter state management system. However I did not succeed. I failed to use and update variables inside my class.

Comment: What is the desired effect/output?

Comment: I would like to be able to use childsName inside my List>Events>Event Title and be able to update it based on certain conditions.

Comment: you cant do a reference to an instance member in an init of another member

Comment: @EricMartin thank you for your answer. What do you suggest I should do instead?

Comment: add static to childsname declaration :  static String? childsName = "Joe";

Comment: honestly i don't understand the picture but it can solve one of your issue

Comment: Declaring childsName as static lets me use this variable. However, when I update childsName later down the road, using the code below, update does not take effect. Still displays the initial value.

 if (choice == 1 && _eventCode == 0) {
    childsName = "Barry";
    }

Comment: Dart does not have a generic template string functionality that would allow you to insert values into your template at runtime. you can read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230201/generic-template-string-like-in-python-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setState()` method to update the state of a widget in Flutter. However, since your `Faith` class is not a widget, you cannot use `setState()` directly. Instead, you can use a state management solution like `Provider` or `Riverpod` to manage the state of your `Faith` class.

Here is an example of how you can use `Riverpod` to manage the state of your `Faith` class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final faithProvider = StateNotifierProvider((_) => FaithNotifier());

class FaithNotifier extends StateNotifier<Faith> {
  FaithNotifier() : super(Faith(childsName: "Joe"));

  void updateChildsName(String name) {
    state = state.copyWith(childsName: name);
  }

  void addEvent(Event event) {
    state = state.copyWith(simulation: [...state.simulation, event]);
  }

  void removeEvent(Event event) {
    state = state.copyWith(
        simulation: state.simulation.where((e) => e != event).toList());
  }
}

class Faith {
  final String childsName;
  final List<Event> simulation;

  Faith({required this.childsName, required this.simulation});

  Faith copyWith({String? childsName, List<Event>? simulation}) {
    return Faith(
      childsName: childsName ?? this.childsName,
      simulation: simulation ?? this.simulation,
    );
  }
}

class Event {
  final int eventCode;
  final String eventTitle;
  final String eventImage;
  final List<Choice> choices;

  Event({
    required this.eventCode,
    required this.eventTitle,
    required this.eventImage,
    required this.choices,
  });
}

class Choice {
  final String choiceText;

  Choice({required this.choiceText});
}
```

In this example, we define a `FaithNotifier` class that extends `StateNotifier<Faith>`. The `Faith` class contains a `childsName` property and a `_simulation` property, which is a list of `Event` objects. The `FaithNotifier` class provides methods to update the `childsName` property and add or remove events from the `_simulation` list.

We then define a `faithProvider` using `StateNotifierProvider`, which creates a new instance of `FaithNotifier` when it is first accessed. We can then use the `useProvider` hook to access the `FaithNotifier` instance and update the state of our `Faith` class.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I appreciate your support. Thx for taking the time to explain in detail. I tried the abovementioned solution. However, I could not get it running. After I have made those changes, main.dart file expected "_simulation list and childsname as arguments". I have almost 30 events for now and I have been keeping them inside Faith class as you will see from my question. Then I was calling "Faith faith= Faith();" inside my main.dart file and using functions to access certain data which was held in Faith class. For instance: "image: AssetImage(storyLine.getEventImage()),"